# Dynamically Table Name in Query based on Count

Tags: sql-server-2012

I would appreciate some suggestions on generating Dynamic Query based on count from my first Query.

For Example: In 757 BTID, We found Max Count of records so it should be our first table in the second Query.
Similarly 706 will be 2nd, 788-3rd, 715 will be 4th table in second query depending on Count.

This Will be different for each user as count is different

**First Query:**

```
SELECT btid, COUNT(*) FROM  dbo.PERSON_EXPANDED
WHERE PID=31226 AND BTID IN (757,706,788,715)
GROUP BY btid
```

***First Query Results:***

> 757 15
>
> 706 14
>
> 788 12
>
> 715 11

**Second Query:**

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.PERSON_EXPANDED E757
INNER JOIN dbo.PERSON_EXPANDED E706 ON E757.PID=E706.PID AND E706.BTID=706 AND E757.EffectiveDate BETWEEN E706.EffectiveDate AND E706.ExpirationDate
INNER JOIN dbo.PERSON_EXPANDED S788 ON E757.PID=S788.PID AND S788.BTID=788 AND E757.EffectiveDate BETWEEN S788.EffectiveDate AND S788.ExpirationDate
INNER JOIN dbo.PERSON_EXPANDED S715 ON E757.PID=S715.PID AND S715.BTID=715 AND E757.EffectiveDate BETWEEN S715.EffectiveDate AND S715.ExpirationDate
INNER JOIN dbo.EMPLOYEE E ON P.PID=E757.PID
WHERE E757.BTID=757
AND E.PID=31226
ORDER BY E757.EffectiveDate
```

Thank you...